# Python lambda function missing lambda keyword but still works

Tags: python, lambda, tinydb

I am using python library `tinydb` to store data.

According to `tinydb` documentation, the proper syntax for an example query is:

```
User = Query()
db.search(User.birthday.year == 1990)
```

Why don't we need:

```
User = Query()
db.search(lambda User: User.birthday.year == 1990)
```

`db.search` is a function that is only called **once**. This means that the function is receiving a fixed value (the result of a comparison) as an input, not a function to serve as a comparator?

How does the `tinydb` library achieve this weird syntax?

Answer (score 4):

`User.birthday.year` isn't really an `int`; it's an object that represents a *query* to retrieve an `int`. The type of this object likewise defines `__eq__` to return not a Boolean value, but a *function* that will return the result of comparing the fetched `int` to 1990.

---

Digging into the code confirms this.

`Query.__getattr__` [returns a new `Query` object](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb/blob/master/tinydb/queries.py#L122), so `User.birthday.year` is *also* a `Query`.

The definitions of [`Query.__eq__`](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb/blob/master/tinydb/queries.py#L157) and [`Query._generate_test`](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb/blob/master/tinydb/queries.py#L144) confirm that `==` also builds a new query.

Comment: So are you saying that the way it achieves this is by using \_\_eq\_\_ dunder magic to (essentially) override/overload the "==" operator?

Comment: Not just essentially; `__eq__` *defines* what `==` means for all types. If you don't override it, you inherit its definition from a parent class, which often means going back to `object.__eq__`, which simply checks for object identity.